# Running a php script as a cron job every 10 seconds

Tags: php, cron

This question may seem repetitive, as there are many threads around with the same subject, but thing is that most solutions seems to be linked with terminal coding, which i'm not comfortable with. The problem is simple i have a php script that needs to be executed very 10 seconds. Cron job in cpanel allows only upto 1 minute. What's the workaround to let cron work every 10 seconds ?

Comment: You could have done some research on your own to find out that the lowest interval for [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a minute. So, there's no way of running cronjobs every 10 seconds.

Comment: No need to downvote as i have already said in my post that cron's lowest interval is 1 minute

Comment: Then why are you asking how to run a cron job every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the cron job run after every minute and in your `php` script the following code example might help you out. I have used counter limit to 6 because this script will run after every ten seconds and six times in one minute.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    sleep(10);
    task();
}

function task(){

}
```

Comment: Make sure you set the maximum execution time. By default most shared hosting sites set max execution time as 30 secs

Comment: You guys are awesome, thank you! My host only permit to run cron jobs each minute. This solution is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple bash-script like

`#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
    php script.php
    sleep 10
done`

Answer (score 1):

CRON jobs are the standard way to run some tasks periodically. Setting cron jobs require access to the terminal. However, some shared hosting providers don't provide this and you need to set it up through their interface.

If you hosting don't provide this you can third-party services that will call you url every 'X' seconds.

Here are few of them:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/
- https://atrigger.com/

You can Google for more

Note: You can have publically expose the PHP file as an url

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GUI Cpanel, select "once per minute" an try with something like the next command:

```
/path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php; sleep 10; /path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php; sleep 10; /path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php; sleep 10; /path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php; sleep 10; /path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php; sleep 10; /path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php
```